# Setting on top dialog if Frame of Dialog in Java

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jframe

I Have one Swing application in java in which I am opening one `Dialog` on click event and after that It will open another dialog on first dialog button click.

But when I click on that second dialog the first dialog is getting visible and that 2nd Dialog is Disable and when I tried to close that one its not closing.But when I close first dialog then its enabled.

So how do I solve this.

I just need to active only first dialog when its open and 2nd when its open.

**Sequence of Dialogs.**

```
JFrame-->Dialog 1 --> Dialog 2
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: how about set the 2nd dialog's parent to the first dialog ,pass the first dialog to the 2nd dialog's constructor.

Comment: is it possible? it will satisfy req of this?

Comment: Can u just give me link for the sample code?

Comment: read Oracle tutorial about modality and modality types, there is a few choices, no idea about which one from three possible scenarios, and aging without an SSCCE/MCVE ....

Comment: well I recommend you read the tutorial,http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html.And note modality as above mentioned.

Comment: but i am not getting if i set it that first as parent of second then how could i will get parent when i set first dialog as parent of 2nd because first have Jframe as parent

Comment: @xiaowang please can u give sample code. because m not able to do it.

Comment: @xiaowang Right bro your tip was great now u can post it as ans and i will accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,since you insist on asking for code,I had make a simple example for you,hope it help!

```
package com.learningjava;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
/**
 * a simple demo to using two dialog
 *
 */
public class DialogFrameDemo extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DialogFrameDemo frame = new DialogFrameDemo();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public DialogFrameDemo() {
        super("Dialog Demo");
        //prepare button in frame
        JButton btnInFrame = new JButton("Click to open a Dialog");
        JPanel framePanel = new JPanel();
        framePanel.add(btnInFrame);
        this.add(framePanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        btnInFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // generate dialog one
                dialogOne = new JDialog(DialogFrameDemo.this,"Dialog one",false);
                JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
                dialogPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
                //prepare button in dialog one
                JButton btnInDialogOne = new JButton("Click to open another Dialog");
                btnInDialogOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        //generate dialog second
                        JDialog dialogTwo = new JDialog(dialogOne,"Dialog Two",true);
                        JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
                        dialogPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
                        dialogPanel.add(new JLabel("Dialog Two"));
                        dialogPanel.add(new JLabel("Lable 21"));
                        dialogPanel.add(new JLabel("Lable 22"));
                        dialogTwo.setContentPane(dialogPanel);
                        dialogTwo.pack();
                        dialogTwo.setVisible(true);
                        dialogTwo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    }
                });
                dialogPanel.add(btnInDialogOne);
                dialogPanel.add(new JLabel("Lable 11"));
                dialogPanel.add(new JLabel("Lable 12"));
                dialogOne.setContentPane(dialogPanel);
                dialogOne.pack();
                dialogOne.setVisible(true);
                dialogOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JDialog dialogOne;
}
```

Comment: u also right +1 and ya u give it first so +1 and green signal to u.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to preview second JDialog as InternalXXXDialog of JDialog1 when button of JDialog1 is pressed.
Look for explanation here.
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object%3aA-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: dude i dont want options panes but i just need Jdialogs boxs in that. cant i use Jdialog only?

Comment: well i wont downvote u because u at least tried. so here bro +1 for your try :)